# Excel VBA TopLeftCell.Row property inconsistent results

Tags: excel, button, vba

Here's the scenario. When a row is inserted in the worksheet there's a worksheet_change event that calls a sub that inserts five pairs of buttons on the row that was inserted. When one of those buttons is clicked it runs a sub that issues a MsgBox that displays the TopLeftCell.Row and Column of the button. Multiple rows can be inserted, each with its five sets of buttons (ten in total). Any button in any row can be selected at any time.

What I'm seeing is that after I open the workbook and press one of the buttons, the MsgBox always displays the correct column, but it seems to get "stuck” on one particular row no matter which row the button that I'm clicking is actually in. If I delete the row it is stuck on then it gets "stuck" on a different row (as long as it also contains buttons). But not all of the buttons will be stuck to the same row.

If I copy two adjacent rows with buttons that are “stuck” on the same row to another location, those buttons are still stuck together except on a different row.

It seems like there’s a problem with the button collection. If I save the workbook the problem goes away. If I insert a new row and the Add_Buttons routine runs again, the problem reappears but involving different rows. So my button routine is probably leaving something temporary behind that gets cleared up when I do a save.

Here's the code that builds the buttons.

```
Public activeWS As Worksheet
Public activeRG As Range

Public Sub Add_Buttons(ByVal myRow As Long)
'Add the five sets of Submit IM and Submit Webins buttons to a new row. The code
'uses named ranges to locate the cells where the buttons should be added so that
'new columns can be added to the spreadsheet without requiring changes to the code.
'The headings must be labeled 'IM#' and 'Webins#'.

Dim i As Long
Dim t As Range
Dim btn As Button


'In each range, place the button below the column label.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For i = 1 To 5

Set activeWS = Sheet1
Set activeRG = activeWS.Range("Scan" & i & "_Hdngs")

'The start of the range plus the position of the specified column in
'the range gives the absolute column location to add the button

'Create the Submit IM button
nCol = activeRG.Cells(1, 1).Column + findCol("IM#", activeRG) - 1
Set t = activeWS.Range(Cells(myRow, nCol), Cells(myRow, nCol))
Set btn = activeWS.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With btn
    .OnAction = "Create_Primary_IM"
    .Caption = "Submit IM"
    .Name = "BtnIM" & myRow & i
    .Font.Size = 10
End With

'Create the Submit Webins button
nCol = activeRG.Cells(1, 1).Column + findCol("Webins#", activeRG) - 1
Set t = activeWS.Range(Cells(myRow, nCol), Cells(myRow, nCol))
Set btn = activeWS.Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
With btn
    .OnAction = "Create_Primary_WAS"
    .Caption = "Submit Webins"
    .Name = "BtnWAS" & myRow & i
    .Font.Size = 10
End With
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here's the code executed by the buttons:

```
Public Sub Create_Primary_IM()
    MsgBox ("Row, Col of pressed button: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row _
        & ", " & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column)
End Sub

Public Sub Create_Primary_WAS()
    MsgBox ("Row, Col of pressed button: " & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Row _
        & ", " & ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Column)
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: *inserts five pairs of buttons on the row* Which row? Being inserted?

Comment: JohnyL - Yes. The Worksheet_Change event uses the Target range to determine what row the buttons should be added to.

Comment: David G. - My question is: why is the TopLeftCell.Row property behaving the way it is? Incorrect after an insert and then correct after a save workbook. The button is on the same row each time. I know it is not a clearly defined problem. I'll try to make the original question clearer.

Comment: You left out the crucial part: The function or sub that returns the row and displays your MsgBox.

Comment: Chrowno - Added code to the end of the original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I believe to be the cause of the problem, its effect on the spreadsheet, and the solution.

The cause was duplicate button names. I had been naming the buttons based on their row and column at the time of creation. The problem is that rows and their buttons could be inserted or deleted anywhere in the sheet. It's not hard to see (except that I didn't see it for a while) that it was possible to insert a row and create its buttons in the same absolute row multiple times. This resulted in buttons with the same .name property.

The effect was that when I clicked one of the duplicate buttons it found the TopLeftCell.Row of the original button with that name, not of the row that the button was actually on. When I saved the file (not closed it) and clicked the same button, it had been renamed to something like 'Button nnn' and the correct row was returned. If I saved the file and re-opened it, the duplicate button name condition was still present. So Excel was replacing duplicate names in that collection when I saved the file, but not committing those changes when I closed the file.

The quickest solution was the easiest as well. I let Excel do the naming. I don't really need the buttons to have names. All I need is the row number. Another solution would be to generate a unique name, but what's the point if that's what Excel is going to do for me anyway?